# syntax error: unexpected end of file when editing code within here documents with emacs. working fine with nano

Tags: bash, emacs, syntax-error, indentation, eof

my `sys_info_script` as edited with `emacs`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Program to output a system information page

declare -r TITLE="System Information Report For $HOSTNAME"
declare -r CURRENT_TIME="$(date +"%x %r %Z")"
declare -r TIMESTAMP="Generated $CURRENT_TIME, by $USER"

function report_uptime {
    cat <<- _EOF_
            <h2>System Uptime</h2>
            <pre>$(uptime)</pre>
            _EOF_
    return
}

function report_disk_space {
    cat <<- _EOF_
            <h2>Disk Space Utilization</h2>
            <pre>$(df -h)</pre>
            _EOF_
    return
}

function report_home_space {
    cat <<- _EOF_
            <h2>Home Space Utilization</h2>
            <pre>$(du -sh /home/*)</pre>
            _EOF_
    return
}

cat << _EOF_
<html>
        <head>
                <title>$TITLE</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>$TITLE</h1>
                <p>$TIMESTAMP</p>
                $(report_uptime)
                $(report_disk_space)
                $(report_home_space)
        </body>
</html>
_EOF_
```

when i execute the script if get an `unexpected end of file` `syntax-error

the same file as edited by `nano`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Program to output a system information page

declare -r TITLE="System Information Report For $HOSTNAME"
declare -r CURRENT_TIME="$(date +"%x %r %Z")"
declare -r TIMESTAMP="Generated $CURRENT_TIME, by $USER"

function report_uptime {
        cat <<- _EOF_
                <h2>System Uptime</h2>
                <pre>$(uptime)</pre>
                _EOF_
        return
}

function report_disk_space {
        cat <<- _EOF_
                <h2>Disk Space Utilization</h2>
                <pre>$(df -h)</pre>
                _EOF_
        return
}

function report_home_space {
        cat <<- _EOF_
                <h2>Home Space Utilization</h2>
                <pre>$(du -sh /home/*)</pre>
                _EOF_
        return
}

cat << _EOF_
<html>
        <head>
                <title>$TITLE</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>$TITLE</h1>
                <p>$TIMESTAMP</p>
                $(report_uptime)
                $(report_disk_space)
                $(report_home_space)
        </body>
</html>
_EOF_
```

this one runs fine

the `sdiff` results on the `cat -A` of the two file (< emacs-edit and > nano-edit):[image]

As you can see **emacs's default space-indentation behavior is probably causing the trouble within `here documents`**.

I'd like to continue to use emacs to edit shell scripts with `here documents`. How do I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the bash manual regarding here docs,

> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading tab
> characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing
> delimiter.  This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be
> indented in a natural fashion.

You must therefore ensure that *only* tabs are used for such
indentation, as bash does not support spaces for indentation in this
situation.

The buffer-local `indent-tabs-mode` variable controls whether or not
Emacs will use tabs in indentation, and then you also need to ensure
that the buffer-local `tab-width` aligns with (in this case)
`sh-basic-offset` so that your indentation will only be tabs, and not
a mixture of tabs and spaces.

See also <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `sh-indentation` <kbd>RET</kbd>

These could potentially be set as file-local variables, to ensure that other Emacs users wouldn't accidentally break this formatting.